# How to clear all input fields within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to clear all input fields (`JTextField`, `JComnboBox`, etc) after record submission within a `JPanel` ?

Currently what I do is, to access to each component and individually use the `setText("")`, etc.

Comment: You can get the components recursively, starting with the `JPanel`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun  Good call on the recursive part.  Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21494050/418556) of doing that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your examples are so good that even if I don't need this method, I still use it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like so:

```
for(JComponent control : parentPanel.getComponents())
{
    if(control instanceof JTextField)
    {
        JTextField ctrl = (JTextField) control;
        ctrl.setText("");
    }
    else if (control instanceof JComboBox)
    {
        JComboBox ctr = (JComboBox) control;
        ctrl.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
}
```

This should iterate over each component within the JPanel and check if the component is a `JTextField` or a `JComboBox` and reset accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Also you could user an index **-1** to reset a **JComboBox**:

```
JComboBox ctr = (JComboBox) control;
ctrl.setSelectedIndex(-1); //-1 indicates no selection
```